# msbuild copy is removing my custom IIS handler mapping

Tags: iis, msbuild

We have a msbuild script for web app deployment. After it does subversion export and build, we copy the files from a build folder into the directory that is hooked up to IIS. Under Handler Mappings in IIS for this app, we have a wildcard script map pointing to a custom executable. We noticed that everytime after deployment, this custom handler mapping would disappear.

I run the msbuild task by task and noticed it was the final copy snippet that was removing the handler mapping. Any idea why and how to prevent it?

```
<!-- comment for testing <Target Name="Install" Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Dev' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Stage' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Release' "
    DependsOnTargets="GetSource;Compile;Test;BackUp">-->
<Target Name="Install" Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Dev' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Stage' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running install for $(Configuration)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackagedFiles_Service Include="$(BuildDir)\$(ProjectNamespace)\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles_Service)"
        DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles_Service->'$(DeployDir)\$(ProjectNamespace)$(AppendEnvSuffix)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more sleuthing it terms out the custom ISAPI handler via IIS is being added to the web.config file directly. So the filecopy obviously overrides the web.config ... solution i guess is to add the handler to the web.config directly.